# Is there short and simple way to compose these functions in scala?

Tags: scala, scalactic

Here is the code:

```
import org.scalactic._
import Accumulation._

def f(x: Int): List[Double] Or Every[String] =
  if (x > 0) Good(List(x, x * 2, x * 3))
  else Bad(Many("One", "Two", "Three"))

def g(y: Double): List[Char] Or Every[String] =
  if (y > 5.0) Good(List('a', 'b', 'c'))
  else Bad(Many("Four", "Five", "Six"))

// Now I need a composition g(f(...)):
// def h(x: Int): List[Char] Or Every[String] = ???

// Straightforward solution
def h(x: Int) =
  f(x).transform(_.map(g).combined, Bad(_)).
    flatMap(item => Good(item.flatMap(identity)))

// h(-1)
// = Bad(Many(One, Two, Three))
// h(2)
// = Bad(Many(Four, Five, Six, Four, Five, Six))
// h(42)
// = Good(List(a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c))
```

Function bodies are replaced with dummy placeholders, domain-specific types are replaced with neutral, but I believe the signatures are straightforward.

How to compose these functions? Is there a builtin method to do it? I would like to avoid flatMap/transform mess.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why your `Good` type is an `Every`? How do you want this to behave? Obviously this is not simple function composition, so I wonder what is wrong with using `flatMap` here.

Comment: Good(Every) comes from parsing nested data structure. 
The expected behavior is:
1. For each double from f call g and produce flat list of Char. Lets think there is some internal logic that converts doubles to char.
2. If f returns Bad, just forward it and do not call g at all.

I don't mind using flatMap, but currently I cannot figure out how it should be user properly: it is easy to call, but how to handle result to avoid deep nested Or[Or[Every[Or[Wtf.

Comment: I think you would rather want to go with `List[Double] Or Every[String]` for arbitrary nested data structures, that's what confused me about `Every`.

Comment: `Every` type was chosen because it is non-empty sequence and it can be optionally constructed: see [Every.from](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalactic.Every$). Anyway, does it make a big difference? I can inline from-like method to my code and use `List` or whatever, but I'm not sure it is significant for my issue of function "composition".

Comment: OK, but so you are not looking for a simple function composition, but a [kleisli composition](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Composing+monadic+functions.html) over some List/Every monad; with included error handling.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to read inside a `for` comprehension. As `Ors` are biased to the `Good` side, you can at least get rid of a little of the `transform` tedium:

```
def h(x: Int): List[Char] Or Every[String] = {
  for {
    y <- f(x)
    z <- y.map(g).combined
  } yield {
    z.flatten
  }
}
```